# How to pull up data in sql?

Tags: php, sql

My question is when I pull up the data with `LIMIT` in query the data can be pull but without `LIMIT` the data won't come out:

```
SELECT a_no as a_no1, status as status1, req_date as req_date1 
FROM transaction_log_ats_201503 
LIMIT 10000
```

Right now the limit is 10000 when the limit greater than 10000 the data won't come out Why?

Comment: post Table & Query as well.

Comment: 'SELECT a_no as a_no1, status as status1, req_date as req_date1
  FROM transaction_log_ats_201503
  LIMIT 10000'                                                                                     right now the limit is 10000 when the limit greater than 10000 the data won't come out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand, I would hazard a guess that your result-set is simply too *enormous!*

From your original post, it seems that you are querying some kind of `transaction_log` table ... *(no doubt, a huge thing...)*, "with **no** limitations at all."  ("Hey, you just want everything ...")  Well, in real-life, that might simply be *too much* to ask-for at one time.  It might simply be a result-set that is "too non-specific for you to handle."

This sort of request might well be "too big for *PHP* to handle," simply because it is unreasonable for you to ever to succeed in packaging "such a massive thing" into "an HTTP response."

Most likely, you will need to re-design this application in such a way that it never attempts to present the query-engine with such a request . . . "at least, not without a `LIMIT`."

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your memory limit

Increase your `memory_limit` in `php.ini` file

`memory_limit` is the Maximum amount of memory a script may consume, it's default set to `128M` change it to `512M`. Its should work for you.

Comment: Its totally depend on your script and your requirments.

Comment: Even so, if the OP is *actually* "querying a `transaction_log`, without imposing any sort of `WHERE` conditions," the situation might still be "hopeless by-design."  Transaction-log tables often consume "tens of *giga*bytes ...")

Comment: agree with @MikeRobinson, redesigning your application is best bet here.